# How to change domain name by htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

My current domain name is abc.com and this working nice but here i want run same domain with different domain name like xyz.com
e.g: "//abc.com/dashboard"
So on "xyz" also see same page like
"//xyz.com/dashboard"
here only change is domain name.
so how can run abc.com domain page on xyz.com

Comment: may be you want simple configure your `xyz.com` domain as alias for `abc.com`? Use `CNAME` DNS records for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz.\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks your replay...is that possible can run both domain url like "dashboard" page will see on both domain "abc.com" and "xyz.com".

Comment: @Atul Yes, it is possible but with above solution you can redirect all xyz.com users to abc.com

Comment: @Atul Just link your domian xyz.com to directory of abc.com

Comment: ok here need work both domain can you tell how this done by htaccess it will be very help full.

Comment: thanks Dj MHA and vp_arth, will let you know after complete this.

Comment: @Atul sure I'm here :)